# How to bridge Network interfaces on Debian/kFreeBSD

Tags: debian, freebsd, bridge, bsd

I have had problems finding a way to bridge network interfaces on Debian/kFreeBSD.

My primary goal is to create 2 - 4 tap interfaces and bridge them with two physical Interfaces.

The Syntax in */etc/network/interfaces* differs a bit from the Linux version.

currently i use the following (on Linux Debian)

(only partial output)

```
auto tap0
iface tap0 inet manual
  pre-up openvpn --mktun --dev tap0
  post-down openvpn --rmtun --dev tap0

auto tap1
iface tap1 inet manual
  pre-up openvpn --mktun --dev tap1
  post-down openvpn --rmtun --dev tap1

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports tap0 tap1 eth1 eth2
  address 10.20.30.40
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

What would be the normal solution, als openvpn on FreeBSD only creates the device if ONE user connects?

i am missing somthing like */etc/rc.conf*

```
cloned_interfaces="bridge0"
ifconfig_bridge0="addm re0 up"
openvpn_if="tap bridge"
```

My general goal would be to switch from Debian Linux to Debian kFreeBSD but i need to sort out some things first.

(reasons for my change are PF (witch I find much more easier to use than iptables) and native ZFS)
but, you could convince from other approaches (BIG FS needed, and btrfs is not stable enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian/kFreeBSD networking components are FreeBSD kernel features and so follows the FreeBSD way.

To create a tunnel interface on FreeBSD, you simply use:

```
ifconfig tun0 create
ifconfig tun0 tunnel <source IP> <destination IP>
ifconfig tun0 up
```

And you probably add some route instructions, to use this tunnel.

---

But you seem to use OpenVPN. I wonder if the OpenVPN configuration wouldn't be able to set this tun0 interface for you, like this is the case on FreeBSD. One of my OpenVPN configuration on a FreeBSD server for example contains these instructions lines:

```
# Run in point to point mode
mode p2p

# Other endpoint
remote <the remote ip or host>
local <your ip>

# Network config
dev-type tun
dev tun0
ifconfig <my local 10.x address> <the remote 10.x local adress>
```

---

For some advanced tunnel configuration, like IPv4->IPv6 tunnels, there is a more advanced driver, called gif0. Here a sample:

```
ifconfig gif0 create
ifconfig gif0 tunnel <your server> <the destination server ipv4>
ifconfig gif0 inet6 <the main ipv6 address>
route -n add -inet6 default <the ipv6 routing address>
ifconfig gif0 up
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i also would like to know about the ways to configure this, as I don't know exactly there to store those configurations. the openVPN things is interesting, and helpful, but I wanted the OpenVPN subnet to be a switched one as i want to provide 4 OpenVPN configurations on the server tcp and udp on port 80 and 443. As i Mentioned in my question, i'd like something as the /etc/network/interfaces file where I could store and set up all this things at startup.

Comment: There are shell commands, so you can create a shell script.

You can also write the commands in /etc/rc.local (before the exit 0; line) to have them executed at startup.